# Is there a way to find out which app on an iPhone just made a sound?

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

My phone is making two sounds, but not providing any other notifications.  I have no idea what is causing this.  How can I track this down?

I have it paired to an Apple Watch, and have Google Inbox installed (but not Gmail)

Comment: I was driven insane for a year... I spent many hours uninstalling apps one by one... In my case it turned out to be email.  If a sender included both my email addresses the first account to receive would give normal notification.  When the same email arrived at the second account I would get a notification sound or vib, but no visual indication.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your Notifications settings (Settings -> Notifications) and see which apps have "Sounds" turned on. I also recommend restarting your phone.